# Cannot open MATLAB from MATHEMATICA

Tags: matlab, matlink

I am using MATLAB R18 and MATHEMATICA 12. I downloaded MATlink to the directory generated by the command:

```
SystemOpen@FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications"}]
```

Next I wrote:

```
Needs["MATLink`"]
OpenMATLAB[]
```

Mathematica starts evaluation but fails to open  MATLAB in the background. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there an information function that returns the details of the MatLab install?  Perhaps you need to point MATLink to your MatLav installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it out, the path that I should define in the system has to be where the `*.dll` files are located, not where the `matlab.exe` is located,

i.e., `c\******\bin\win64`

not `c\******\bin`

Comment: Add comments to your existing post or to answers. Delete this "answer" and add it as a comment to your initial post

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: This resolves the issue. The directory win64 has to be added to the $PATH variable on Windows.